# Views changes their attributes inside PerformSelectorInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c

I heard say that the views can have their attributes changed only in the main thread, and never in a secondary thread, which makes certain background processing.

for example, I can not run one of these commands below in a method that is running in background mode:

```
- addSubview
- removeSubview
- setFrame
- setBackgroundColor
- etc...
```

Unfortunately it seems that something went wrong and I could set the background within a method that is running in background mode plan, doing so the rule is broken, example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(modoOff:) withObject:@"parametro"];
}

-(void)modoOff:(NSString*)valor{

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

}
```

why this is happening? will be that this rule only applies to older versions of iOS? I am using ARC with ios 7.1.

Comment: it might work sometimes, it might not work sometimes, sometimes it will crash.. you will never know.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a case of you cannot change the UI on a background thread, it is a case of you should not change it on a background thread.  For reasons why I suggest you read: http://chritto.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/updating-the-ui-from-another-thread/

Comment: I have other question, If inside a void method running in background mode call another method void, this method will run on background too?